# rack: saving connection without saving config to db

Tags: ruby, rack

I am creating a web based database PG client. built using ruby with only rack.

I have this endpoint at `/connection`. It need to be accessed with POST with connection string with json body. This is part of the code that handle the `/connection` endpoint

```rb
    class Connection
      def call(req)
        req_body = JSON.parse(req.body.read)
        connection_string = req_body["connection_string"].to_s
        connection = PG::Connection.new(connection_string)

        Rack::Response.new
      rescue PG::ConnectionBad
        Rack::Response.new([], 400, {})
      end
    end
```

the code basically just make a connection using connection string come from request body. Then if connection got no error, just return OK, but if have error it return 400.

But i want to save this connection so i can use it to query in another endpoint.
My idea is just to create a sqlite database and save this connection string and maybe a session_id. so every time the request come i just read it and do connection again and do query.

Is there any efficient way? that is not use sqlite

Thanks

Comment: A database connection cannot be saved into a database, because the established database connection is made of a physical and logical connection between both processes. Not different from an internet connection that which cannot be stored into a database and re-use at a different place later on. Once a connection is closed, it needs to be re-opened. The only thing you can do is to use a connection pool that keeps the connection open all the time. 
Why do you want to do that? Is parsing the JSON or re-connecting too slow?

Comment: i want to save the connection by saving the connection string or the credential in a sqlite db to re open later, or re open on every query. not the connection variable i made when it connected to db. what i want to do is when user already hit connection end point then it return success to the client, then if client hit query endpoint, it use still the same connection as before @spickermann

Comment: i actually do not know if re opening connection slow or not, but i wonder if there is another way to do it. i do not familiar with connection pool yet, but i can give a try @spickermann